# are there any tree libraries/widgets for (n)curses

Tags: ncurses, curses

I wondered if there were any tree libraries available for (n)curses.

I'm trying to write a component that shows a tree of folders & was curious if there was a prebuilt curses component that could do this.

I've checked 'core' curses as well as libraries like CDK - and I can't seem to find anything.

If none exists, I'm not averse to building my own - but I can't seem to locate any decent tutorials on doing this, so any help in this regard would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[Urwid](http://urwid.org/) has a tree widget, FWIW.

UPDATE: 2020-10-01 - I wrote my answer back in 2010, when I wrote a tree widget for Urwid since I couldn't find anything.  [Urwid](http://urwid.org/) still has the tree widget, but these days, I would look at [Python's prompt-toolkit](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/) or [one of the alternatives](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/PROJECTS.rst).

Answer (score 2):

"I'm trying to write a component that shows a tree of folders"

CDK has the `CDKFSELECT` widget.

It displays a list of directories and files, that might work for you, or the 
source code of CDKFSELECT might be leveraged for your own custom written 
solution.

```
CDKFSELECT *fSelect = 0;

/*
Height of zero means to extent of xterm
Width of zero means to extent of xterm
*/
int HEIGHT = 0;
int WIDTH = 0;

char *title = new char[strlen("Pick a file to open") + 1];
strcpy(title, "Pick a file to open");

char *prompt = new char[strlen("==> ") + 1];
strcpy(prompt, "==> ");

char *directoryAttribute = new char[strlen("</B>") + 1]; /* bold */
strcpy(directoryAttribute, "</B>");

char *fileAttribute = new char[strlen("</N>") + 1]; /* normal */
strcpy(fileAttribute, "</N>");

char *linkAttribute = new char[strlen("</D>") + 1]; /* dim */
strcpy(linkAttribute, "</D>");

char *sockAttribute = new char[strlen("</D>") + 1]; /* dim */
strcpy(sockAttribute, "</D>");

boolean displayBox = TRUE;
boolean displayShadow = FALSE;

fSelect = newCDKFselect(pCdkScreen,
          TOP, LEFT, HEIGHT, WIDTH,
          title, prompt,
          A_NORMAL, '_', A_REVERSE,
          directoryAttribute, fileAttribute, linkAttribute, sockAttribute,
          displayBox, displayShadow);

char *filename = activateCDKFselect(fSelect, 0);
/*
2014-06-13, using DDD, filename being correctly populated
by CDK
*/

/* do other stuff... */

/*
 free the memory of any dynamically created objects
 that were created with new or malloc, or such
*/
destroyCDKFselect(fSelect);

delete [] title;
delete [] prompt;
delete [] directoryAttribute;
delete [] fileAttribute;
delete [] linkAttribute;
delete [] sockAttribute;
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`dialog`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) program (which has a documented library interface) has a ["tree"](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog_lib.html#h3-dialog_treeview) widget.  The program works with (n)curses, and unlike [CDK](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/cdk.html), is suitable for use with UTF-8.

[image: dialog - tree view]

It also has a [file(/directory)](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog_lib.html#h3-dialog_fselect) selection widget.

[image: dialog - file-selection]

There's also [`wcd`](https://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/) (though like **[`mc`](http://midnight-commander.org/)**, reusability of the *library* is uncertain).  However, it is a good example of what OP probably wants:

[image: screenshot converted from wcd page]

Regarding **[`urwid`](http://urwid.org/)**, that's debatable.  Under the hood you may not actually have curses.  For what it's worth, a screenshot of the *treeview* script:

[image: urwid treeview]

and on my Debian/testing system, the script doesn't use ncurses.  It's hardcoded (i.e., using `raw_display`).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Midnight commander source code (http://www.midnight-commander.org/) It has a tree store widget.